# Подход к изучению паттеронов в php

Tags: php, ооп, шаблоны-проектирования

Почти изучил ООП. Скоро придёт время для паттернов проектирования.
Пожалуйста, дайте совет, на какие паттерны стоит обратить внимание в первую очередь.

Comment: Имхо, стоит сперва без паттернов поработать... Когда они вам понадобятся то уже многие на автомате будете понимать и применять

Comment: если учишь для работы, то в первую очередь на эти https://www.php-fig.org/psr/ в ряде вакансий некую часть из них требуют. да и некоторые из них порой необходимы. если память не изменяет использование любой кодировки кроме utf-8 boomless в php равно выстрелу себе в ногу, ибо метка BOOM интерпретатором воспринимается как старт вывода и ставит крест на возможности использовать http заголовки, coocie и в общем-то всё предвыводное. на счет обоснованности прочих сказать увы нечего

Comment: @puffleeck BOOM это когда бабах случился какой-то, а в начале файла там BOM. не ясно правда к чему это вообще тут упомянуто

Comment: @teran, `BOM` ужс, аж целую лишнюю букву написал, и как теперь жить то, трагедия прям. `к чему` в качестве примера того сколь неочевидными могут быть грабли и к тому сколь простым может быть решение. p.s. там где нашел линк на перечень psr, использование utf bomless вроде упомяналось как одно из них

Comment: `psr` это не паттерны, а набор рекомендаций которым надо следовать.

Comment: @u_mulder не **надо**, а **можно** (ну, или, **желательно**) xD

Comment: @u_mulder, `это не паттерны`, потому и указаны в комментарии а не в ответе, алло. думаю лишними знания таких вещей уж точно не будут. или будут? хотел бы себе сотрудника незнающего их? а? =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В коммент как-то слишком много получится, поэтому в ответ.

Основные паттерные, которые как правило изучают **вообще** вот такие:

```
- Singleton (Одиночка)
- Adapter  (Адаптер)
- Простая фабрика
- Abstract Factory  (Абстрактная фабрика)
- Factory Method  (Фабричный метод)
- Strategy  (Стратегия)
- Bridge  (Мост)        
- Prototype  (Прототип)
- Composite  (Компоновщик)
- Decorator  (Декоратор)
- Facade  (Фасад)
- Flyweight  (Легковес/Приспособленец)
- Proxy  (Прокси)
- Chain of Responsibility  (Цепочка ответственности)
- Command  (Команда)
- Interpreter  (Интерпретатор)
- Iterator  (Итератор)
- Mediator  (Посредник)
- Memento  (Хранитель)
- Observer (Наблюдатель)
- State (Состояние)
- Template Method  (Шаблонный метод)
- Visitor (Посетитель)
- Builder (Мост)
```

На самом деле паттернов **гораздо больше**. Но до других ещё дойти надо.

Но из представленных выше как правило начинают со следующих, по важности:

```
- Singleton (Одиночка) - хоть кто-то будет говорить, что это антипаттерн, но он №1 в изучении каждого программиста
- Abstract Factory  (Абстрактная фабрика), Factory Method  (Фабричный метод), Простая фабрика --- лучше изучить ВСЕ ТРИ сразу. Это поможет в дальнейшем
- Strategy  (Стратегия)
- Command  (Команда)
- State (Состояние)
- Template Method  (Шаблонный метод) --- как правило понадобится если захочется свой mvc фреймворк сделать. Но, конечно, не только в этом смысл
```

Далее можно

```
- Bridge  (Мост)
- Facade  (Фасад)
- Decorator  (Декоратор)
- Builder (Мост)
- Chain of Responsibility  (Цепочка ответственности)
```

и остальные

Comment: главное мыслить головушкой при этом, а не шаблонами.

Comment: Это да. Но это уже совсем другая история ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯